# How to convert a point cloud to mesh using python

Tags: python

so I have a .PCD or .ply file that I need to convert to a mesh and then display the mesh... are there any efficient methods to do this?

Comment: please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("file.pcd")
    print(pcd)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])

#So far I can only show the point cloud

Comment: Here we like to help fixing code issue. I invite you to read the guide [ask] to improve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the convex hull mesh of the point cloud and then visualize

http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.geometry.PointCloud.compute_convex_hull

```
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("file.pcd")
hull_mesh, points = pcd.compute_convex_hull()
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([hull_mesh])
```

Comment: That gives me the following error... TypeError: draw_geometries(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (geometry_list: List[open3d.open3d.geometry.Geometry], window_name: str = 'Open3D', width: int = 1920, height: int = 1080, left: int = 50, top: int = 50) -> None

Comment: I can't run this right now, buy try verifying the type of `hull_mesh` or call `instanceof`. According to the docs it should be a open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh, which should inherit from Geometry

Comment: Unless the docs are incorrect about the return type, I'll guess you've misplaced an extra comma somewhere in your code causing python to create a tuple

Comment: pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\PointCloud\\sample2.ply")  
print(type(pcd))
hull_mesh = pcd.compute_convex_hull()
print(type(hull_mesh))
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([hull_mesh])

Comment: Try print `hull_mesh` itself and see what it contains. If it's a tuple, perhaps one of its elements is the TriangleMesh object

Comment: Ah yes that worked perfectly thanks, it was the only element in the tuple for some reason